# How to solve "no generic parameters allowed"

Tags: generics, nim-lang

**TL;DR:** *If you have a similar problem, check first that you haven't done something completely stupid like confusing a `:` with a `=`. I was so baffled by the error message that I managed to reproduce a stupid mistake by yet another stupid mistake, so have a good laugh:*

I came upon a problem where I was struggling with the error `no generic parameters allowed`. The problem is probably best explained in a simplified from: The problem of comparing a tuple only by its first element. Consider this example:

```
import algorithm

# just a dummy type emphasizing that it should not be
# used for the comparison
type
  NotComparable = object

# generic proc to compare a tuple by the first element
proc cmpByKey[K,V](x: (K,V), y: (K,V)): int = 
  system.cmp(x[0], y[0])

# now the actual challenge: how to write a function which
# takes some collection of tuples and defines a local
# key comparator for the given tuple.
proc sortByFirstTupleElement[K,V](data: seq[(K,V)]) =
  let compare = cmpByKey[K,V]
  sort[(K,V)](cmp: compare)

let data = @[(2, NotComparable()),
             (1, NotComparable()),
             (3, NotComparable())]

sortByFirstTupleElement[int, NotComparable](data)
```

This example produces `Error: no generic parameters allowed for sort`. I have tried all kinds of syntactic variations, also defining the comparator proc nested. What I do not understand: Why is the comparator still considered generic? I was expecting that within `sortByFirstTupleElement` the types `K` and `V` are instantiated types from the calling context, i.e, `int` and `NotComparable`. Therefore I expected `cmpByKey[K,V]` to be the concrete `cmpByKey[int,NotComparable]`. Is there a syntactic trick to make the comparator concrete?

If this is not possible, what are the possible workarounds here? Maybe not just specifically in this example, but in general? I guess this problem arises every time a generic proc has to pass on another proc which involves the generic type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `sort` with the wrong parameters. You don't pass the `data` parameter to sort, and `data` is not a var parameter, so it isn't mutable. Also, `cmp` is not a named parameter, so just pass the comparison function directly. E.g.:

```
import algorithm

# just a dummy type emphasizing that it should not be
# used for the comparison
type
  NotComparable = object

# generic proc to compare a tuple by the first element
proc cmpByKey[K,V](x: (K,V), y: (K,V)): int = 
  system.cmp(x[0], y[0])

# now the actual challenge: how to write a function which
# takes some collection of tuples and defines a local
# key comparator for the given tuple.
proc sortByFirstTupleElement[K,V](data: var seq[(K,V)]) =
  let compare = cmpByKey[K,V]
  data.sort(compare)

var data = @[(2, NotComparable()),
             (1, NotComparable()),
             (3, NotComparable())]

sortByFirstTupleElement(data)
```

Also, the `let compare = ...` is superfluous. You can call `data.sort(cmpByKey[K,V])` directly.

You get the error message because you're using the object constructor syntax (`cmp: compare`) rather than the named parameter syntax (`cmp = compare`), which makes Nim look for an object type called `sort` rather than a procedure called `sort`. The error message is still a bit confusing, but that's where it's coming from.

Comment: Oh, what a stupid mistake... This error message made me worry about the entirely wrong thing all the time. Similarly in my original problem. There, the issue was further obfuscated by the following surprising behavior: For some reason, if the comparator argument has a default value of `system.cmp`, my passed-in function is ignored (cannot reproduce trivially though). Maybe this is the reason why `sort` doesn't have a default value for `cmp` in the first place?

Comment: I've updated the post to explain the reason for the confusing error message.